# VBA merge files in current dir using cmd.exe

Tags: file, shell, vba, merge, cmd

I have an Excel sheet in one folder and try to merge certain files within this folder to one file using the following code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  Dim RET As Variant
  RET = Shell("cmd.exe copy  files1.txt + file2.txt out.txt", 0)
End Sub
```

As a return value for RET i get 1560. No error while debugging, but no "out.txt" either.
What's wrong with my code? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you miss the /C in the cmd arguments and the path.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  Dim RET As Variant
  RET = Shell("cmd.exe /C copy  C:\Data\files1.txt + C:\Data\file2.txt C:\Data\out.txt", 0)
End Sub
```

The return value not equal 0 indicates the process is started (it is the actual process id)

Comment: can you try cmd /c echo hallo > out.txt

Comment: add start before the cmd.exe, does files1.txt exist?

Comment: Adding start throws an error file not found because "start" is not a prog on my computer... Yes, the files do exist

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19306/discussion-between-lumpi-and-rene)

Answer (score 1):

The VBA way;

```
Function readFile(path) As String
    On Error GoTo ERR_IO
    Dim hF As Integer: hF = FreeFile
    Open path For Input As #hF
    readFile = Input$(LOF(hF), hF)
ERR_IO:
    Close #hF
End Function

Function writeFile(path, buffer) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo ERR_IO
    Dim hF As Integer: hF = FreeFile
    Open path For Output As #hF
    Print #hF, buffer
    writeFile = True
ERR_IO:
    Close #hF
End Function

Sub merge()
    Dim buffer As String
    buffer =          readFile("C:\xxx\files1.txt")
    buffer = buffer & readFile("C:\xxx\files2.txt")

    writeFile "c:\xxx\out.txt", buffer
End Sub
```